# Is it possible to merge specific stanzas of an nginx(1) file that exist across different nginx conf files

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm not an `nginx` expert, so I have a question for the community.

I have an `nginx.conf` file like the one below. I need to dynamically add or remove server entries (e.g. `svcXX.example.com`) on demand.

Instead of programmatically editing this file (which could lead to file corruption over time), is there an `include style` way to accomplish this, where after issuing a `nginx -s reload`, `nginx` read in other files and merge entries for that particular stanza / section.

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
events {}

stream {  

  map $ssl_preread_server_name $targetBackend {
    svc01.example.com svc01.example.com:1443
    svc02.example.com svc02.example.com:2443
    svc03.example.com svc03.example.com:3443
  }   
 
  server {
    listen 443; 
        
    proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    proxy_timeout 3s;
    resolver 1.1.1.1;
    
    proxy_pass $targetBackend;       
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to achieve, but there is an `include` directive. http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know, but my issue is not knowing how to use it in this context (ie, to include new entries within a stanza). But I'll take a look. I'm typing by phone. =:)